# If $P$ and $Q$ are two $3\times3$ non-indentity matrices with real entries such that $PP^T=QQ^T=I$. Find $\det(P+Q)$ with $\det(PQ)<0$

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus

If $P$ and $Q$ are two $3\times3$ non-indentity matrices with real entries such that $PP^T=QQ^T=I$ (where $P^T, Q^T$ are transpose of matrices $P$ and $Q$ respectively) and $\det(PQ)<0$, then which of the following is/are always correct (where $\det$ stands for determinant of a matrix)

(a) $\det (P+Q)<0$

(b) $\det(P+Q)=0$

(c) at least one of the $\det(P-I)$ or $\det (Q-I)$ will be zero

(d) $\det (P^{-1}+Q^{-1})=0$

**Given Solution:**

I given solution at starting He took $P^T(P+Q)Q^T=(P+Q)^T$

**My doubt:** How did he think of this step immediately? Is there anything which I must know about matrices to solve these kind of problem? Is given step such obvious?

I know how to prove $\det(P+Q)=0$ if I knew Given step in solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to avoid the tricky step.

One has $\det(P+Q)=\det(P)\det(I_n + P^{-1}Q)=\det(P)\det(I_n + P^TQ)$.

Now, since $P$ and $Q$ are orthogonal matrices, then $P^TQ$ is orthogonal too, and since $\det(P^TQ)=\det(PQ) < 0$, then $P^TQ$ has $-1$ as an eigenvalue, so $\det(I_n + P^TQ)=0$.

Comment: is there any wiki link to this property $\det(P+Q)=\det(P)\det(I_n + P^{-1}Q)=\det(P)\det(I_n + P^TQ)$.?

Comment: No need to any link : the first step only comes for the factorisation $P+Q=P(I_n+P^{-1}Q)$, and the second one from the fact that $P^T=P^{-1}$.